# authentication state changes return always null

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I am trying to create a stream of my user modal based on the authenticate services of fire base.

create user object base on FirebaseUser:

```
 UnicoUser? _userFromFirebaseUser(User? user){
    if (user != null) {
      UnicoUser? _unicoUser;
      DatabaseService(uid: user.uid).getUserFromUserId().then((value){ _unicoUser = value; print("user id: "+ value.uid);});
      return _unicoUser;
    }
    return null;
    }
```

create the auth change user stream:

```
  Stream<UnicoUser?> get unicoUser {
    return _auth.authStateChanges().map(_userFromFirebaseUser);
  }
```

the implement in the widget:

```
StreamBuilder(
          stream: AuthServices().unicoUser,
          builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<UnicoUser?> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
              return const Loading();}
            else if(snapshot.hasData ){
              return LoggedInWrapper(currentUser: snapshot.data!,);}
            else if (snapshot.hasError){
              return const Center(child: Text("Something went wrong"),);}
            else {
              print("snapshot is: "+  snapshot.data.toString());return const Authenticate();}
          },
        )
```

even if the user is authenticated and the unicouser object is not null the snapshot data is null..
output:

```
Performing hot reload...
Syncing files to device AOSP on IA Emulator...
Reloaded 0 libraries in 111ms.
I/flutter (22920): snapshot is: null
I/flutter (22920): user id: fnWyLWrCznQDSmZGr6kShpXSsK52
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your `_userFromFirebaseUser` function. Unfortunately, you cannot handle `async` values this way. The function returns before your `_unicouser` is set by `then`. You need to use an `async` function and `await` the result like this:

```
Future<UnicoUser?> _userFromFirebaseUser(User? user) async {
  if (user != null) {
    return await DatabaseService(uid: user.uid).getUserFromUserId();
  }
  return null;
}
```

Then you should be able to use it like this:

```
Stream<UnicoUser?> get unicoUser {
  return _auth.authStateChanges().asyncMap(_userFromFirebaseUser);
}
```